# На что ругается maven?

Tags: java, maven

Добрый день, не получается собрать проект maven постоянно выдаёт ошибку. Жалуясь на "Неразрешимый родительский POM" в чём может быть дело ? 
часть xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.kurento.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>kurento-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>kurento-group-call</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Kurento Java Tutorial - Group Call</name>
<description>WebRTC many to many video call</description>

<url>http://www.kurento.org/docs/${project.version}</url>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>

<organization>
    <name>Kurento</name>
    <url>http://www.kurento.org</url>
</organization>

<scm>
    <url>https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java</url>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git://git@github.com:Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java</developerConnection>
    <tag>develop</tag>
```

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-group-call:[unknown-version] (/home/tol/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-group-call/pom.xml) points at org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-group-call instead of org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-tutorial, please verify your project structure @ line 5, column 10
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-group-   call:[unknown-version]: Failure to find org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-  tutorial:pom:6.6.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10
@
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-group-call:[unknown-version] (/home/tol/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-group-call/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-group-call:[unknown-version]: Failure to find org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-tutorial:pom:6.6.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,  please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: Мавен ищет артефакт `org.kurento.tutorial:kurento-tutorial:pom:6.6.0` в [Maven Central](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/kurento/) и не находит. я тоже не нахожу.

Comment: @Nofate что можно сделать ?

Comment: Разобраться, что за библиотеку вы используете, и где ее брать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось проще, я скачал проект master с git, собрал jar через maven и запустил его.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что в вашем pom.xml есть директива

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.kurento.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>kurento-tutorial</artifactId>
    <relativePath>какой-то путь</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Указанный в `relativePath` путь ссылается не на pom.xml, в котором `artifactId` содержит `kurento-group-call`, а должен содержать `kurento-tutorial`.

Comment: Да всё есть кроме  <relativePath>какой-то путь</relativePath> Обновил вопрос добавив часть xml. Добавлял всё так же

Comment: А этот родитель есть в каталоге верхнего уровня?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду файлы <groupId>org.kurento.tutorial</groupId> если да то его нет <artifactId>kurento-tutorial</artifactId> это папка в которой содержится запускаемый мной проект.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что директива `parent` указывает на наличие родительского проекта, который, без указания `relativePath` должен находиться в родительском каталоге. Если он и не нужен, тогда просто удалите директиву. А если нужен, то надо создать в родительском каталоге pom.xml, содержащий правильные `groupId`, `artifactId` и другие необходимые вам директивы.